# Calculate distance between two coordinates on a globe

Tags: python, coordinates, distance, coordinate-systems

I get two coordinate pairs in the form `90°0′0″N 0°0′0″E` as string and want to calculate the distance between those points on a sphere with radius R=6371km.

I found two formulas on the internet [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), the "haversine" and the "spherical law of cosines", but they don't seem to work. For a 90° angle which should return `2*pi*R / 4`, the haversine operates correct but the cosines fail and return 0. A different point with more random coordinates returns false values with both algorithms: the haversine is too high and the cosines are too low.

Is my implementation wrong or did I chose an incorrect algorithm?

How should I make these calculations (coordinate pairs to distance on globe surface) instead?

(And yes, I know that I'm not checking for N/S and E/W yet, but the tested coordinates are all in the north-eastern hemisphere.)

Here's my Python 3 code:

```py
import math, re
R = 6371
PAT = r'(\d+)°(\d+)′(\d+)″([NSEW])'

def distance(first, second):
    def coords_to_rads(s):  
        return [math.radians(int(d) +int(m)/60 +int(s)/3600) \
                for d, m, s, nswe in re.findall(PAT, s)]

    y1, x1 = coords_to_rads(first)
    y2, x2 = coords_to_rads(second)  
    dx = x1 - x2  
    dy = y1 - y2  

    print("coord string:", first, "|", second)
    print("coord radians:", y1, x1, "|", y2, x2)
    print("x/y-distances:", dy, dx)

    a = math.sin(dx/2)**2 + math.cos(x1) * math.cos(x2) * math.sin(dy/2)**2  
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))  
    haversine =  R * c  

    law_of_cosines = math.acos( math.sin(x1) * math.sin(x2) + \
                                math.cos(x1) * math.cos(x2) ) * R

    print("HS:", round(haversine, 2), "LOC:", round(law_of_cosines, 2))

    return haversine
    #return law_of_cosines

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def test(result, correct):
        print("result: ", result)
        print("correct:", correct)

    test(distance("90°0′0″N 0°0′0″E", "0°0′0″N, 0°0′0″E"), 10007.5)
    test(distance("51°28′48″N 0°0′0″E", "46°12′0″N, 6°9′0″E"), 739.2)
    test(distance("90°0′0″N 0°0′0″E", "90°0′0″S, 0°0′0″W"), 20015.1)
    test(distance("33°51′31″S, 151°12′51″E", "40°46′22″N 73°59′3″W"), 15990.2)
```

Here is some output:

```
coord string: 90°0′0″N 0°0′0″E | 0°0′0″N, 0°0′0″E
coord radians: 1.5707963267948966 0.0 | 0.0 0.0
x/y-distances: 1.5707963267948966 0.0
HS: 10007.54 LOC: 0.0
result: 10007.543398010286
correct: 10007.5

coord string: 51°28′48″N 0°0′0″E | 46°12′0″N, 6°9′0″E
coord radians: 0.8984954989266809 0.0 | 0.8063421144213803 0.10733774899765128
x/y-distances: 0.09215338450530064 -0.10733774899765128
HS: 900.57 LOC: 683.85
result: 900.5669567853056
correct: 739.2
```

Comment: Good question, but I wonder if it should go to [codereview.SE]? I know a lot of questions in which you already have a working or nearly-working code sample are considered to be off topic here and on topic there, but I'm not sure of the exact "cutoff" between the sites.

Comment: @DavidZ As I understand it, CR only wants working code snippets that look for optimization. therefore I posted it here. But it wouldn't be  my first one that gets migrated from SO to CR or back...

Comment: Makes sense to me. Anyway, I checked the site you linked against [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) and there seems to be an inconsistency in the definition of the haversine formula (although I'm not sure it really is an inconsistency). Have you looked into that?

Comment: @DavidZ 3 golden rules for On-Topic [CodeReview.se] questions: Does the code work as intended? Is it actual code (not stub, example or hypothetical)? Is the OP happy to receive feedback about any aspect of said code? If yes to all 3, CR is the place to go.

Comment: In this case, the code obviously fails due to "Not working as intended".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you mixed up `x` and `y` in your calculation of `a`. You're supposed to take the cosine of latitude (`y`), not longitude (`x`).

I discovered this by changing your `distance` to `angular_distance` (i.e. don't multiply by `R`) and adding some additional tests:

```
test(angular_distance("90°0′0″N 0°0′0″E", "89°0′0″N, 0°0′0″E"), math.radians(1))
test(angular_distance("90°0′0″N 0°0′0″E", "80°0′0″N, 0°0′0″E"), math.radians(10))
test(angular_distance("90°0′0″N 0°0′0″E", "50°0′0″N, 0°0′0″E"), math.radians(40))
test(angular_distance("90°0′0″N 0°0′0″E", "50°0′0″N, 20°0′0″E"), math.radians(40))
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I simply changed the lines `y1, x1 = coords_to_rads(first)` and `y2, x2 = coords_to_rads(second)` and swapped the `x`s and `y`s.