# Storing the values of an iteration to a numpy array - Python, Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

So I'm struggling to make this code more useful for larger data-sets. Here is the code, I will explain it thoroughly afterwards:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold='nan')

tri_nums = [3, 2, 1]


paths = [1, 3, 4, 5]

vol_list = [10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 25]

n = 0

array_list = []

while n <= len(tri_nums):
    for num in tri_nums:
        print "assigning volume", vol_list[sum(tri_nums)-len(vol_list)+1]
        volume_array = np.zeros(shape = (6, 6))
        volume_array[paths[num-1],paths[num]] = vol_list[sum(tri_nums)-len(vol_list)+1]
        array_list.append(volume_array)
        print paths[num-1], paths[num]


    tri_nums.pop(0)
    paths.pop(0)
    n+=1
    print paths
    print tri_nums


final_array = sum(array_list)
print array_list
print final_array
```

Starting with `tri_nums`:
The values of `tri_nums` will always be a list of the triangular numbers of the length of `paths`.  So a `paths` list of say, `[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]`, will give a `tri_nums` of `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`.

`tri_nums` are also correlated to the number of values in `vol_list`.  As you can see, there are three `10`'s in `vol_list`.  The number of `10`'s is equal to the first value of `tri_nums`.  There are also two `15`'s and a `2` for the second value of `tri_nums`.  This pattern will never change! Another example of this is:

```
paths = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]

tri_nums = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

vol_list = [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 250, 250, 250, 250, 25, 25, 25, 10, 10, 15]
```

The list `paths` (in the original case) is made up of four 'nodes', nodes 1,3,4 and 5.  Between each adjacent node there is a path, i.e. path 1-3, 3-4, 4-5.

As one can see, `volume_array` is a 6x6 array and is made up of zeros.  The row values in `volume_array` that are to be changed correspond to the first value of each path i.e. `1`,`3`, `4`. The column values correspond to the second number of each path i.e. `3`, `4`,`5`.

Here comes the tricky bit!

The values in `vol_list` are allocated to the aforementioned array items as follows:

1. For each value of `tri_nums` a value in `vol_list` is added to `volume_array`.  The row value within this array is defined by the first value of a path i.e. `[4]`and the column value is defined by the second value of a path (for the value `[4]` this will mean `[5]`).
2. For `tri_nums[0]`, the value `10` is added three times, once to `volume_array[4][5]`, once to `volume_array[3][4]` and once to `volume_array[1][3]`.
3. For `tri_nums[1]` the value `15` is added twice, once to `volume_array[4][5]` and once to `volume_array[3][4]`.
4. For `tri_nums[2]` the value `25` is added once to `volume_array[4][5]`.
5. Finally, all of the values in of the arrays generated in the previous three steps are added together to get `final_array`.

Another thing worth mentioning is that the sum of `tri_nums` is equal to `len(vol_list)`.  Furthermore `tri_nums[n]` is always > `tri_nums[n+1]`.

Ideally I would like to implement this code for `path`'s, `tri_num`'s and `vol_list`'s with hundreds of items in them. The method I am using now would mean I need to make hundreds of while loops by hand.  How can I make the `while` loops work simultaneously so I can avoid the "hundreds of while loops" scenario?

Everything is working just fine, but the final output is:

```
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.  10.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.  25.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.  25.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

Meaning that the final value of `vol_list` which is (`25`) has not been assigned to `array_list[4][5]` and thus was not in `final_array`.  It just needs to do one more loop and it'll work, I'm not sure how to get it to do the last loop though.

Please let me know if anything is unclear!

Thanks

Comment: `list` is a datatype - it shouldn't be used as a variable name (rename it). `while count < 1:` is redundant since you'd get the same result if you removed it. It only makes sense to leave it in if you'll later want to iterate more than once.

Comment: anything you can do by hand you can have a computer do. Think about the steps that you would take to do it by hand. Then make the computer do that. Sometimes it's harder to make the computer to that, but YMMV.

Comment: Since you asked, the code sample is a bit on the long side, and the description is also moderately complex. I think it would make a clearer question if you interspersed the parts of the description with the corresponding pieces of the code. Adding sample output in a couple places would help further. That being said, I _kind of_ get what you're doing; let me see if I can come up with an answer.

Comment: Also, considering [these criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280970/calculate-distance-between-two-coordinates-on-a-globe?noredirect=1#comment60190055_36280970) it's possible this is better placed on [codereview.SE] (but if that's the case, it can be migrated, no need to manually repost it there).

Comment: Also also, now that I'm looking at the code, some things don't make sense. E.g. each of your `while` loops is subtly different. For example, the first one references _two_ entries of `paths` at each iteration, namely `paths[n]` and `paths[n+1]`, but the other loops reference _one_ entry of `paths` each time through. Each loop computes its indices into `volume_array` differently. The third loop increments `b` but doesn't actually use its value anywhere in the loop. Are these intentional inconsistencies? Why? What do the three indices `n`, `a`, and `b` mean?

Comment: What if `tri_nums[1] > tri_nums[0]`? You'll get an `IndexError` in the second loop, when `n-a` becomes negative. Is it guaranteed that `sum(tri_nums) == len(vol_list)`? Do you need one loop for each element of `tri_nums`?

Comment: @AndrewEarl Thanks for the edits, but I'm still confused. Your question now contradicts itself in a few places. Your edit says that the first `while` loop allocates _three_ values, but earlier in the text you say it allocates _two_ values. Similarly, the edit says the second `while` loop allocates two values but earlier you say it allocates the last value. Your description says the `25` should wind up at `volume_array[3][4]` but your code actually puts it at `volume_array[4][5]`. I still don't understand why the first loop references two elements of `paths` and the others reference only one.

Comment: Maybe this would help: would you consider changing the inputs to `tri_nums = [4,2,1]`, `paths = [1,4,2,6]`, and `vol_list = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]`? Then can you _manually_ compute the result (`final_array`) you would expect for these inputs, and check that your code gives the correct result? If it doesn't, please either fix the code so that it does give the expected result (if you can), or tell us in your question what the expected result is and how you obtained it. Don't be afraid to delete outdated text from the question.

Comment: @DavidZ I've made my last edits, the code does work now, so sorry, I got confused by starting at zero and not 1.  Rookie error.

Comment: @AndrewEarl No problem. But you still haven't addressed all the issues I brought up. Why doesn't the third loop use `b`? Why is the indexing pattern different in all three loops? Again, it would really help if I knew what the output is supposed to be for the parameters I gave in my last comment, except with one change: `tri_nums = [3,2,2]` would be more informative than `tri_nums = [4,2,1]`. I'm also hoping the system will allow us to continue this exchange in chat, at some point.

Comment: @DavidZ on `b`:  `b` is not used in the third loop because using it doesn't give me the results that I want and I suppose I got lazy when using `a` did.  This is why the indexing pattern is different.  I've worked on the problem today and have come up with a much better code, which is really close to a solution, but still has one problem in it.  It's in the main body, apologies if this is bad stackexchange practice.

Comment: Somehow I didn't see the bit at the end of your post when I posted my previous comments (which I just deleted). This is definitely much better, although good SE practice is to remove obsolete parts of your post when you edit. In your case, I'd recommend getting rid of everything in the post except the new code sample, and writing up a brand new description. In any case, the added code sample is probably enough for me to suggest a solution. Let me take a few minutes to work out an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you miss the last element of your array is that you're incrementing `n` at the same time you're popping elements off of `tri_nums`. Look at the values of `n` and `tri_nums` at the beginning of each iteration of your `while` loop:

```
iteration    n    tri_nums    n <= len(tri_nums)
0            0    [3, 2, 1]   True
1            1    [2, 1]      True
2            2    [1]         False
```

You should either keep `n` at 0, and make your condition `while tri_nums` (which is equivalent to `while len(tri_nums) > 0`), or probably better, you should avoid modifying `tri_nums` and just use a `for` loop. You would then need to modify the inner loop to only iterate over part of `tri_nums` each time, like so:

```
for n in xrange(len(tri_nums)):
    for num in tri_nums[n:]:
```

That being said, the whole approach of iterating over lists, creating multiple arrays, and adding them all up is quite inefficient. Because this isn't [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), I won't get into all the inefficiencies, but there are a few key ones I want to mention:

- You have a lot of structure in your input data that you could take advantage of
- You should try to use Numpy vectorized operations instead of native Python operations as much as possible
- You keep putting numbers at the same indices, so you can add up the numbers first and only create the array at the end

With all that in mind, I'd recommend changing your code so that `vol_list` only contains each number *once*.

```
vol_list = [10, 15, 25]
```

You can then construct the array you need by adding your numbers up first, and then sticking the resulting sums in the array. Numpy conveniently includes the `cumsum` function to compute partial sums of an array:

```
>>> np.cumsum([10, 15, 25])
array([10, 25, 50])
```

and it allows you to specify many values at once in its indexing operations. So your entire algorithm can be reduced to this:

```
final_array = np.zeros((6, 6))
final_array[paths[:-1], paths[1:]] = np.cumsum(vol_list)
```

If your memory requirements become problematic for long lists, you might want to use [Scipy's sparse matrices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) for storage, instead of ordinary Numpy arrays.

Comment: This is incredible.  I'm just doublechecking that it works for bigger datasets, but so far so good.  You sir, are a wizard and a scholar.

Comment: Glad to help, but I do hope you'll keep in mind how difficult it was to understand the question in the first place, and use that to improve your future questions. I think you could stand to be a _lot_ more careful when describing how your code works. It would also be helpful to clean up your question one more time for future readers. (And if my answer solved your problem, it'd be great if you accept it by clicking the green checkmark.)